# Lotus Notes: Press OK button from script in DialogBox

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there a method to press "OK" button of a dialogbox by using script ?
i want to obtain the same result like user press ok button but using script

Comment: Have you tried javascript?

Comment: i don't know javascript code to do this... can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not possible. if you want to "automate" this, you have to get rid of the Dialogbox.

BUT: You of course could "mimic" the behaviour by just using NotesUIDocument.Close, or use some JavaScript code as umeli mentioned in his comment...